# Polling epics behavior

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I am writing an epics that polls a server every certain amount of seconds, in this case, 3 second start delay, polls every 5 second, using timer by pipe-ing it, but I am not sure the reasoning behind this behavior.

My epics is not waiting for my inner from to complete, so the output is really weird.

I have tried changing the map and using exhaustMap, but am not sure if I am barking up the right tree.

```
export const testingEpics = action$ => {
  // Stop upon a end pending action trigger, for debugging/stopping if needed
  const stopPolling$ = action$.pipe(ofType(END_PENDING_ACTIONS));
  return action$.pipe(
    // On begin pending actions
    ofType(BEGIN_PENDING_ACTIONS),
    switchMap(action =>
      // At a 5 second interval
      timer(3 * 1000, 5 * 1000).pipe(
        // Stop when epics see a end pending action
        takeUntil(stopPolling$),
        switchMap(() =>
          // Get the db
          from(getDb()).pipe(
            mergeMap(db => {
              console.log('Run again!!');
              return from(
                new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000))
              ).pipe(
                // what happens if action is still running but no internet?
                // delay(9.9 * 1000),
                // actions is an array from the db
                // switchmap at top is reason for it, handle for future. lol
                map(actions => console.log('Hello world'))
              );
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
};
```

The expected result will be

```
(Initial delay 3 seconds) 
Run Again!!
(Wait's 10 seconds for inner promise to complete)
Hello world
(Subsequent delay of 5 seconds)
Run Again!!
(Wait's another 10 seconds for inner promise to complete)
Hello world
(Subsequent delay of 5 seconds)
Run Again!!
(Wait's another 10 seconds for inner promise to complete)
Hello world
(Subsequent delay of 5 seconds)
.
.
.
```

Comment: What does `getDb` return? Does that actually make the call to your server, or is the call to the server simulated by the `new Promise`?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the all `switchMap` to `concatMap`, if you want all request to go through and queque, `exhaustMap` will skip the source observable emission until inner one completes, so you might miss a lot of request. On the other hand `switchMap` will cancel the inner observable once parent observable emits, so your `getDb()` promise will get canceled

Answer (score 0):

`interval` and `timer` may be used to generate a loop that executes with a frequency immune to the length of time it takes to actually poll your server. Based on your "expected result" description, it looks like you *want* the frequency to be affected by the length of time it takes to actually poll your server. I'm thinking of your use case like the following (synchronous) loop:

```js
delay(3) // synchronously wait 3 seconds
while (!stopped) {
  pollServer() // synchronously poll server; may take N seconds
  delay(10) // synchronously wait 10 seconds
}
```

I would use `repeatWhen` to construct the above loop in an epic. The `repeatWhen` makes it easy to start the 10 second delay only after the "loop iteration" completes. You simply delay the complete event within the notifications observable:

```js
export const epic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(BEGIN_PENDING_ACTIONS),
    exhaustMap(action => // ignore actions while the loop is already running
      of(action).pipe( // re-pipe so we can attach `takeUntil` to stop running the loop
        delay(3000), // this is the initial delay
        mergeMap(() =>
          from(getDb()).pipe( // this is the start of the loop iteration
            mergeMap(db => ...), // this is where you poll the server and emit Redux actions
            repeatWhen(complete$ =>
              complete$.pipe(
                delay(10000), // on complete, wait 10 seconds, then repeat!
              )
            ),
          )
        ),
        takeUntil(action$.pipe( // stop on end
          ofType(END_PENDING_ACTIONS)
        )),
      )
    ),
  )
```

Note that in the above example, `repeatWhen` will simply re-subscribe to `from(getDb())`. The value of `db` will always be the cached value from the first iteration. If you need to re-execute `getDb()` on every iteration, then substitute for `defer(() => from(getDb()))`.